# get a basic c++ program to compile using clang++ on Ubuntu 16

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, clang++

I'm running into problems compiling on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (server).  It compiles okay if I don't include the `-std=c++11` bit.  Clang version is 3.8.

```
>cat foo.cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    string s(argv[0]);
    cout << s << endl;
}


>clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ foo.cpp
In file included from foo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1938:44: error: 'basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>' is missing exception specification
      'noexcept(is_nothrow_copy_constructible<allocator_type>::value)'
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::basic_string(const allocator_type& __a)
                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1326:40: note: previous declaration is here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY explicit basic_string(const allocator_type& __a)
                                       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: does it work without -stdlib=libc++?

Comment: so then it's picking up the libstdc++ headers and not libc++.  I think that's normal on a linux distro.

Comment: So then how do I get it to use the libc++ headers?

Comment: why not just use libstdc++?

Comment: @xaxxon same issue for me, the problem is that with gcc-4.8 compiler I cannot have c++14 features. Using clang instead of gcc was a solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have installed `libc++-dev` on ubuntu 16.04 in the (correct) expectation that it ought
to let you build with `clang++` using `libc++` and its headers for your
standard library.

It *ought* to, but in the presence of `std=c++11` (or later standard), it
doesn't, because of [Debian bug #808086](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=808086),
which you have run into.

If you wish to compile with `clang++` to the C++11 standard or later, then
until ubuntu gets a fix for this you will have to do so without `libc++`, using
`libstdc++` (the GNU C++ standard library) instead, which is the default behaviour.

```
clang++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp
```

or:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ foo.cpp
```

will work.

Comment: I've re-opened the same bug on Launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libc++/+bug/1610168). While in Debian this is a minor inconvenience as (as of today) it only ships Clang 3.8 in experimental, Ubuntu 16.04 comes with Clang 3.8 and a broken libc++, which is totally nuts.

Comment: This is now fixed in 16.04.

Answer (score 22):

Until the Debian bug mentioned in Mike Kinghan's reply is fixed, just adding the missing (but required) `noexcept` specification to the ctor definition manually allows to work around the problem, i.e. you could just add

```
#if _LIBCPP_STD_VER <= 14
    _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_copy_constructible<allocator_type>::value)
#else
    _NOEXCEPT
#endif
```

after the line 1938 of `/usr/include/c++/v1/string`.

Comment: Note that after I made this change, I also had to install libc++abi-dev and then ln -s /usr/include/libcxxabi/__cxxabi_config.h /usr/include/c++/v1/__cxxabi_config.h

Comment: Interesting, I didn't have to do this with clang 3.8.0-2 under Debian Sid.